# Displaying two properties in one itemcontainer with WinRT

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml

I have a class student with a property 'name' and 'education'. I have filled an ObservableCollection with students and set the ItemsSource of a gridview to this ObservableCollection.

Now I know that I can set the displaymemberpath to show a property in the gridview. However I am trying to get both properties in the same gridview with an ItemTemplate. I want them horizontally aligned with the properties above each other. Like this:

Student1  ......    Student2  .......    Student3   ......   Student4    .......  Student5

Education1  ...  Education2 ...   Education3  ...  Education4  ...  Education5

I have tried the following:

```
<Style TargetType="GridView">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This aligns the class horizontally as follows, but I am not able to set the DisplayMemberPath of a StackPanel:

App.Student ... App.Student ... App.Student ... App.Student ... App.Student

Can anyone give me a tip how I can reach the example above, with an ItemTemplate and One container?

**P.S.** I know that this can be accomplished easily with two seperate containers/stackpanels or in other ways. But I am trying to learn something more about ItemTemplates, hence the reason why I want one container with an ItemTemplate which displays two propertys.

Comment: What does your output look like?

Comment: @bit see my question, I inserted the output

Comment: Did you try to set the Orientation of the stack panel to vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably see - `DisplayMemberPath` can only be set to one property, so if you need to display anything more than just a very basic single string of text - you may need to set the `ItemTemplate` like so.

```
<GridView ...>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Education}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Of course you might also have a single string property with two lines of text separated with `"\r\n"`  - that might work in some very simple cases.

Comment: Thank you for the xaml solution, now I can convert it myself to an style/resource! But that is done in a second.